# Pivot table with 2 different sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have 2 different excel sheets

```
tab1

  A B C D E
1
2
3
```

and table 2

```
  T U V W X
1
2
3
```

Let's say in B and U columns we have the same kind of data for instance "name of owner" and in C and V we have "number of animals owned", in D and W we have "country of the animal". The oter data are not relevant for my pivot table but I still want to be able to find them if needed.

I want a single pivot table which uses tab 1 and 2. I want to have D (or W as they are the same type of data) as filter and to see for every "name of the owner" the "number of animals owned" according to tab1 in a column and in another column the "number of animals owned" ccording to tab2.

I tried to use the pivot table helper but I didn't manage to use filters and I could obtain a pivot table by "name of owner" only if I used the datasets with as a first column B and U.

```
Thank you.
```

Answer (score 0):

I may misunderstand where you are hitting a wall. Sounds like you may already know that you can create a Pivot Table using multiple source tables or sheets of data. And this works fine (but does require that columns be named or captioned the same in each data source, of course). And you can specify multiple filters as needed.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Consolidate-multiple-worksheets-into-one-PivotTable-report-3ae257d2-ca94-49ff-a481-e9fc8adeeeb5

Comment: Ive read this page already but it is not clear to me how to add filters and how to achieve what i want without unselecting the first column.

Comment: Unfortunately, Excel's consolidated Pivots are not as flexible as standard Pivots with a single data source. Some of those limitations are reviewed here, along with some good suggestions. Using PowerQuery would be an excellent option: http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot08.html.  

As another workaround that _may_ work for you, you could setup a new column as the first column in your Pivot ranges, make this calculated so that it appears as the Name of the Owner followed by the Country, for example:  "Morg (USA)".  Then you could easily filter by Country using Label Filter > Contains ... "USA".